# Different ways of initializing an object with default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

```
class A {};

A a;// 1
A a{};// 2
A a = {};// 3
A a = A();// 4
```

There seems to be all options. Are 1, 2 and 3 are same and just the matter of style or there is some difference? 4 supposed to first create a temporary object and then assign it to an `a`, but it will happen only if I will turn off comliler's optimization completely, right?

Comment: I don't understand, what does your question have to do with Object Oriented Programming?

Comment: Supplementary reading on the options available: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization . Some entertaining viewing on just how deep the rabbit hole can go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

Comment: Note that starting with C++17, [the 4th option does not actually create a temporary](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be37efb0da691eaf). In fact, it doesn't even require a move constructor be available (but [C++14 does](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d29cf447c394a308)).

Comment: [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) in C++ is more complicated than it should and has lot of corner cases. All your options might have different behaviors (but for your `A`, they are similar).

Answer (score 2):

1. Is different because it does default initialisation. This does not matter in case of `A` however, because there are no members to initialise.